# Linking ArcGIS to Access

Tags: arcgis-desktop, database, ms-access

I am working to link spatial data in ArcGIS 10.3.1 (parcels with many attributes) to an Access database of customers.

Initially all I need is to identify which parcels are in my database and append the landowner names to the attribute table.

I think I can accomplish this a single time with a join.

However, I am constantly adding new customers to Access.

My desired end result is to be able to sort the parcels that are customers at any given time without having to re-join the tables.

So my larger question is:

Can (and should) I keep that link live so that it updates my parcel attributes when I have a new customer?

I would only be editing one way - data entered in Access and sent to Arc.  I have no need to use the spatial data in Access.

Is there a good solution for this?

Comment: I was able to connect my database using the Add OLE DB Connection.  From there I was able to use the connected DB's tables to create the product that I needed through model builder. I am still trying to write a script to automate and fine tune this, but that's another topic.

Comment: To enable automation, I was able to connect to the database through Python script using (abbr. for char limit):

def estcnxn():
        dbPath = 'X:\somedatabase.mdb'
        accessProvider = 'Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source=' + dbPath
        cnxn = adodbapi.connect(accessProvider)
        return cnxn

def readingdb():
        cnxn = estcnxn()
        c = cnxn.cursor()
        query = """SELECT * FROM aTable;"""
        sourceData = pandas.read_sql(query, cnxn) #uses pandas to read data and put it in a "dataview"
        cnxn.close()
        return (sourceData)

Comment: Haha, can't edit.  You'll have to figure out the white space.

Answer (score 1):

Personally, I'm not sure without any script you can update features attributes automatically, but if you want create a connection between ArcGIS and Access you should read this instruction

"[Connecting to a Microsoft Access database in ArcGIS](http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/10.3/manage-data/tables/connecting-to-a-microsoft-access-database.htm)"

and

["Understanding how to use Microsoft Access files in ArcGIS](http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/10.3/manage-data/tables/understanding-how-to-use-microsoft-access-files-in-arcgis.htm#)"

and get help from

"[Link Excel Table to Access/Arcmap Personal Geodatabase Table](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/176734/link-excel-table-to-access-arcmap-personal-geodatabase-table)"

moreover

"[Arcgis table and Excel sheet dynamic linking](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/176379/arcgis-table-and-excel-sheet-dynamic-linking)"

I believe these references would be helpful. I hope so. Excel and Accese are approximately same.

Comment: I think dynamic linking is what I am looking for.  As usual, knowing the right word makes finding the solution so much easier.  Thank you very much for taking the time to respond.